# How to turn these text lines into CSV lines with regex (PCRE)?

Tags: regex, csv, pcre

Given the following input

```
1 foo 745
2 baz 746
unneeded characters
```

I expect an output as follows

```
1;foo;745
2;baz;746
```

I used a regex to get the desired output. However, I can't get rid off the garbage characters.

Regex: `/(\d)\s([a-z]+)\s(\d+)\s+|[\S\s]+$/x`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W0zsHz/1)

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/hOqGwm/1

Comment: Please explain the requirements, especially for the "garbage" part.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The "garbage" part refers to characters I don't want to match.

Comment: Yes, and what are they? How can the garbage part be differentiated from the non-garbage part? See my link to regex101, and anubhava's approach. Right now, all approaches are valid until you explain what the garbage really means.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Don't focus on the garbage: it can be ANY character.

Comment: Stephen, so how can you define the start and end boundaries of the "garbage" part? And please let know if any solution works for you. (and come on: your question is about how to remove "garbage", and you say "do not focus on garbage").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for matching:

```
^(\d+)\h+([a-z]+)\h+(\d+)(?:\R\S*$)*
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/W0zsHz/7)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in captured group #1
- `\h+`: Match 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `([a-z]+)`: Match 1+ lowercase letters in captured group #2
- `\h+`: Match 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in captured group #3
- `(?:\R\S*$)*`: Match zero or more *garbage* characters that means non-whitespace characters in a separate line

Comment: If the garbage contains a digit, the [`(\d+)\h+([a-z]+)\h+(\d+)\D+`](https://regex101.com/r/W0zsHz/4) won't work.

Comment: ok I updated my answer to take care of that. Though garbage character is a vague term. It can have different meaning to different people.

Comment: Your anwser provided the expected output. Thank you :)